How to load a specific stock and date and mark the date with a vertical dashed line using Trading Vue Js library?
I'm building a stock analysis dashboard using TradingVue Js (TVJS). The dashboard features a heatmap with color-coded stock performance data (Red: Alert, Yellow: Warning, Green: Healthy).
To provide deeper insights, I've implemented a mini-chart (Not TVJS) above the heatmap. Users should be able to select a specific date on the mini-chart, and the main TVJS chart should automatically load data for that date. Additionally, a vertical dashed line should appear on the TVJS chart to highlight the selected date. (Image Attached)
Challenges:

Synchronizing date selection between the mini-chart and TVJS chart.
Dynamically loading TVJS chart data based on the selected date.
Adding a vertical dashed line to the TVJS chart at the selected date.

I've attached screenshots to illustrate the desired behavior.
Feature Draft
At the moment, we are experimenting with URL search strings but that won't sole the vertical line challenge.
Any guidance or code snippets related to these challenges would be greatly appreciated.
